# Storing failed states locally

Tags: front-end, state

I’m currently developing a web application and am struggling to think of a design for the front-end.

In the front-end the user can input 1-n values and it will be split up into 1-n API calls. The api does some processing for 2-10 seconds and stores it in the database if it is successful. Right now I just have it so that there is no update on the UI when submitted, and when the database changes the UI reflects that. This doesn’t help the user understand which inputs failed or are still loading.

One approach I was thinking of was to add to the UI immediately and if it’s successful delete it from the local state as it will render from the database state automatically. If it fails then we keep it in the local storage so it persists along refreshes. If on the refresh it detects the server state has some failed value from the local state then it will delete from the local state. Is this the standard approach or are there better designs for a system like this?

The one problem I’m seeing is that this may break the single source of truth principle.

Answer (score 0):

I see you doubt it is a good idea to come up with your own special "state-caching local-storage" solution to the problem that has already been solved by others a 100 times, and you are right.

It is better for you to go with what is the best practice for the tech-stack you are using. If you dont know how its done with the tools you have, just keep researching the tools. Every application framework will have its own way how to update the UI once the data in the database have been changed. If you dont use any application frameworks, its time to start.

Comment: Sorry I either misunderstood you or was unclear in my question. I don’t really want to cache anything from the server. I just have some inputs that might fail so I still want to show them in the UI, but they don’t need to be stored in the database as it is most likely junk.